# jQuery on edit switch first div to secondary div within li dynamically

Tags: jquery, css, html, dynamic

I am having some issues, I am working on "In-Place Editing" implementation and want to retrieve the ID dynamically about two divs within one li, the first div is visible by default, and the second is set to display: none; when I click the pen "icon" (span) I want to switch i.e. set the first div: display: none; and the second display: block; This is my jQuery so far:

```
$('.edit-tools').each(function () {
             var pen = this;
             $(pen).click(function () {
                 var div_id_first = $(this).closest(".school").attr('id');
                 var div_id_second = $(".school-edit").attr('id');

                 console.log(div_id_first);
                 console.log(div_id_second);

                 $('#' + div_id_first).css("display", "none");
                 $('#' + div_id_second).css("display", "block");

                 $('.edit-tools').attr("disabled", true); 
             });
         });
```

**EDIT: The problem is with the second ID, that's because the other div is outside, and the pen (span) is within the first div that's why closest(); method works.**

The main question is how can I get the id of the second one,

```
 <li>
    <div id="09990-view"></div>
    <div id="09990-edit" style="display: none;"></div>
 <li>
```

Here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tF6nD/3/

Comment: Could you show us your HTML too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working example:
http://jsfiddle.net/tF6nD/5/

You need to get the children based on the `li` element.

```
         $('.edit-tools').click(function () {
             var div_id_first = $(this).closest("li").find(".school").attr('id');
             var div_id_second = $(this).closest("li").find(".school-edit").attr('id');

             console.log(div_id_first);
             console.log(div_id_second);

             $('#' + div_id_first).css("display", "none");
             $('#' + div_id_second).css("display", "block");

             $('.edit-tools').attr("disabled", true); 
         });
```

Comment: IMO, @Evan there may be a lot of schools listed with each li e.g. 

<li>
  <div id="09990-view"></div>
  <div id="09990-edit" style="display: none;"></div>
</li>

<li>
  <div id="09991-view"></div>
  <div id="09991-edit" style="display: none;"></div>
</li>

Comment: Re: Why not explain what isn't working? 

According to the Console in Firebug nothing is retrieved i.e. ID!

Comment: @JohnSmith also, see my edit, I changed `each` to `.click` - there is no point in having both.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27404/discussion-between-evan-and-john-smith)